# How to find the orthogonal complement of C(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

So I'm doing this review sheet for an exam and I've come across a question I'm stuck on.

It gives me some $3\times 4$ matrix $A$, asks me to determine whether or not $v$ is in the column space of $A$ if it is find all vectors $x$ which satisfy $Ax=v$ (which is just Span? right?) then use the fundamental theorem of linear algebra to find the orthogonal complement of $C(A)$, which stats

$$(\text{Row} A)^{\perp} = \text{Nul} A\quad \text{or} \quad(\text{Col} A)^{\perp} = (\text{Nul} A)^T.$$

So I thought that you find Nul $A$, and Col $A$ but then how do you find $(\text{Col} A)^{\perp}$?

If you wanna see the full problem let me know.

*Large edit below*

Ok let me try an example(since I can't answer my own questions yet)

M =
\begin{array}{cc}
1&2&3&3\\
1&2&1&1\\
2&2&2&3\\
\end{array}
**v** = \begin{array}{cc} 2\\1\\-3\\ \end{array}
so M = **v** reduces to 
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0&-1&0&-5\\
0&1&2&0&11\\
0&0&0&1&5\\
\end{array}
so we get that it is in the col **v** is in the col space of M
so I'm trying to find the orthogonal complement of **v** right? So to find Nul(A)$^T$ 
is just 
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0&-1&0&0\\
0&1&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
\end{array}
which transposes and that's my Nul(A)$^T$ ? And is that my answer? Am I done?

Comment: Find the null space of the transpose of this matrix...this will be a set of column vectors. Then the orthogonal complement of the column space, by this fundamental theorem, is the set of these column vectors.

Comment: You have a typo: $(\operatorname{Col}A)^\perp =\operatorname{Nul}(A^\top)$. There are different ways to find $\operatorname{Nul}(A^\top)$, one being to use your usual algorithm for nullspace (but applying it to $A^\top$, not $A$), the other being to find constraint equations for $Ax=b$ to consistent.

Comment: @afedder: OK, I couldn't be a mind reader. Please edit once more and say that the orthogonal complement is the *span* of these vectors, or that these vectors form a *basis*. :)

Comment: That is already taken care of with the statement "this will be a set of column vectors"...I didn't specify that it was a span, but I assume the OP knows how to find and interpret a null space in the typical context. @TedShifrin

Comment: @afedder I updated with an example, is that right or am I just not getting it.